# Strange behavior of tessFactors inside tessellation stage

Tags: directx-11, hlsl, tessellation

i've noticed some super stange behavior on my nvidia 860m. Im programming some 3d engine and i'm using tessellation for terrain rendering.

I use a simple quad tessellation algorithm.

```
struct PatchTess
{
    float EdgeTess[4] : SV_TessFactor;
    float InsideTess[2] : SV_InsideTessFactor;
};

PatchTess ConstantHS(InputPatch<VS_OUT, 4> patch)
{
    PatchTess pt;

    float3 l = (patch[0].PosW + patch[2].PosW) * 0.5f;
    float3 t = (patch[0].PosW + patch[1].PosW) * 0.5f;
    float3 r = (patch[1].PosW + patch[3].PosW) * 0.5f;
    float3 b = (patch[2].PosW + patch[3].PosW) * 0.5f;
    float3 c = (patch[0].PosW + patch[1].PosW + patch[2].PosW + patch[3].PosW) * 0.25f;

    pt.EdgeTess[0] = GetTessFactor(l);
    pt.EdgeTess[1] = GetTessFactor(t);
    pt.EdgeTess[2] = GetTessFactor(r);
    pt.EdgeTess[3] = GetTessFactor(b);

    pt.InsideTess[0] = GetTessFactor(c);
    pt.InsideTess[1] = pt.InsideTess[0];

    return pt;
}

[domain("quad")]
[partitioning("fractional_even")]
[outputtopology("triangle_cw")]
[outputcontrolpoints(4)]
[patchconstantfunc("ConstantHS")]
[maxtessfactor(64.0f)]
VS_OUT HS(InputPatch<VS_OUT, 4> p, uint i : SV_OutputControlPointID)
{
    VS_OUT vout;
    vout.PosW = p[i].PosW;
    return vout;
}

[domain("quad")]
DS_OUT DS(PatchTess patchTess, float2 uv : SV_DomainLocation, const OutputPatch<VS_OUT, 4> quad)
{
    DS_OUT dout;

    float3 p = lerp(lerp(quad[0].PosW, quad[1].PosW, uv.x), lerp(quad[2].PosW, quad[3].PosW, uv.x), uv.y);
    p.y = GetHeight(p);

    dout.PosH = mul(float4(p, 1.0f), gViewProj);
    dout.PosW = p;
    return dout;
}
```

This code above isn't the problem, just want to give you some code context.

The Problem occurres in this function:

```
inline float GetTessFactor(float3 posW)
{
    const float factor = saturate((length(gEyePos - posW) - minDistance) / (maxDistance - minDistance));
    return pow(2, lerp(6.0f, 0.0f, factor));
}
```

When i use the debug mode in Visual Studio, everything works pretty finde, tessellation works as it should. But in release mode, i got flickering of the terrain patches.

And now the super strange thing: When i change the function and switch from pow to just a linear function or something else, everything works as exspected.
So this works fine:

```
inline float GetTessFactor(float3 posW)
{
    const float factor = saturate((length(gEyePos - posW) - minDistance) / (maxDistance - minDistance));
    return lerp(64.0f, 0.0f, factor));
}
```

EDIT:
changing the line:

```
pt.InsideTess[0] = GetTessFactor(c);
```

to

```
pt.InsideTess[0] = max(max(pt.EdgeTess[0], pt.EdgeTess[1]), max(pt.EdgeTess[2], pt.EdgeTess[3]));
```

does the job.

It seems that sometimes the pow function is calculating values (withing the valid range of 64.0f) that are not valid with the edge tess factors.

Also keep in mind, that this problem just appears when running in release mode and not in debug mode (VS 2013).

Does anyone know restrictions for the combination of the tessfactor values? I didn't find any information on msdn or any similar pages.

Thanks

Comment: The only thing I can think of is somehow the `pow` variant is producing a `NaN` value, maybe due to an optimization of the `2` literal. If it's not showing up in the debugger, you can try adding an `isnan` check of the return value and writing to a UAV which you can read back and print on the CPU.  Or just write the return value to the UAV directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried that and the pow functions seems to be ok. After some further trial and error i found the problem being the tessFactors. Somehow there must be some restrictions with value combinations. 

I've changed the line of the insideTessFactor to pt.InsideTess[0] = max(max(pt.EdgeTess[0], pt.EdgeTess[1]), max(pt.EdgeTess[2], pt.EdgeTess[3])); and it works without any problems. Didn't find any comments on that on msdn or similar pages.

Comment: changed the description, due to new information

Comment: There shouldn't be any limitations on the relationship between `SV_TessFactor` and `SV_InsideTessFactor`. If either is `0` though the patch will be culled. It's suspicious though that this only occurs in DEBUG builds.  This suggests a race condition somewhere that only shows up in RELEASE builds (when things run faster).  The next thing I'd try is building for RELEASE but trying to capture a frame using the [VS Graphics Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873207.aspx).  I'd recommend using VS 2015 as the tools have improved since 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Newest driver update solved the Problem.